# What is the invention?

Tags: us20170093910

In reference to the patent: [US20170093910](https://www.google.com/patents/US20170093910)

The patent describes the honeypot which has been used for a decade. There is no invention.

Comment: Be advised this is an application, not a patent. It may or may not get granted and even if it is, the claims are likely to be narrowed.